# What is the relationship between an import statement and its classpath?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am having some difficulty understanding the relationship between the import statements in a gradle file and the eventual import statements in the actual Java code. For example if I have...

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
```

then what could the classpath be?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'xxxxxx'
    }
}
```

In .net the import staments match the references in the config. So if I have

```
Zoo.animals.monkeys
```

Then my import would be...

```
Zoo.animals.monkeys.chimps
```

Comment: Not sure but I don't think there's a relation. Import statements refer to a class or to a package to import, classpath refers to a library name&version

Comment: None. Import statements don't have classpaths. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import has *nothing* to do with CLASSPATH.  It saves you keystrokes, allowing you to use short class names instead of full ones (e.g. `ResultSet` instead of `java.sql.ResultSet`) when you type your source code.

CLASSPATH matters at compile time, allowing the compiler to resolve static types, and at runtime when the class loader brings your byte code into the JVM at first reference.

You can't infer anything about CLASSPATH based on packages.  What if that class is in a JAR?  The CLASSPATH will refer to the JAR, not the package.

Most of the applications I write use 3rd party JARs that I load in using Maven.  I maintain the pom.xml, not a CLASSPATH.